# How well does Visual Web Developer 2010 Express support PHP?

Tags: php, visual-studio

How well does Visual Web Developer 2010 Express support PHP?

Answer (score 2):

There is no PHP support in Visual Web Developer 2010 from Microsoft.

A quick google brings up http://www.jcxsoftware.com/vs.php ... but I haven't seen/tested it before so I can't say it'll work.  Note that you have to shell out 100 bucks for it.

In addition, you CAN trick visual c++ into thinking that .php files are .cpp files.  You would get basic syntax highlighting [if, while, for]... http://www.cumps.be/visual-studio-2008-and-php-coloring/

There were also a few attempts to write intelligent PHP support into Visual Studio [ie: http://php4vs.codeplex.com/]... they all failed eventually.

Answer (score 2):

that's what [WebMatrix](http://asp.net/webmatrix) is for, PHP/Web development.

Answer (score 0):

There is http://www.jcxsoftware.com/vs.php which enables Visual Studio to work properly with PHP files. Alternatively have a look at this blog post that explains how to use PHP with Visual Studio (http://www.cumps.be/visual-studio-2008-and-php-coloring/)

Answer (score 0):

VWD 2010 Express does not support php. If you want to highlight php syntaxes then use notepad++, which is free.